# Called id for nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, shapado

I am trying to install Shapado on my OS X machine. Ultimately I want to install it on Heroku, so if anyone has an install guide please let me know.

I believe the dependecies are all OK, and mongodb is running. I get an error when I run:

```
$rake bootstrap RAILS_ENV=development

rake aborted!
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id


Seans-MacBook-Pro:shapado sean$ rake bootstrap RAILS_ENV=development
/Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/maruku-0.6.0/lib/maruku/input/parse_doc.rb:22:in `<top (required)>': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
Loaded
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/sean/Dropbox/rails/shapado/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/sean/Dropbox/rails/shapado/Rakefile:7)
Missing GeoIP data. Please run '/Users/sean/Dropbox/rails/shapado/script/update_geoip'
>> Setting up Twitter provider
>> Setting up Facebook provider
>> Setting up Identica provider
>> Setting up Github provider
>> Setting up LinkedIn provider
rake aborted!
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

Tasks: TOP => bootstrap => setup:default_group
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Seans-MacBook-Pro:shapado sean$ rake bootstrap RAILS_ENV=development
/Users/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/maruku-0.6.0/lib/maruku/input/parse_doc.rb:22:in `<top (required)>': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
Loaded
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/sean/Dropbox/rails/shapado/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/sean/Dropbox/rails/shapado/Rakefile:7)
Missing GeoIP data. Please run '/Users/sean/Dropbox/rails/shapado/script/update_geoip'
>> Setting up Twitter provider
>> Setting up Facebook provider
>> Setting up Identica provider
>> Setting up Github provider
>> Setting up LinkedIn provider
rake aborted!
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

**EDIT**
Output from --trace flag on rake

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil,  use object_id
/Users/sean/Dropbox/rails/shapado/app/models/group.rb:641:in `set_shapado_version'
```

The problem code is this:

```
def set_shapado_version
  self.shapado_version_id = ShapadoVersion.where(:token => 'free').first.id
end
```

Comment: Can you trace the rake task? `rake bootstrap --trace RAILS_ENV=development`

Comment: Thanks alto, I've updated the post with the trace info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in app/models/group.rb change

```
def set_shapado_version
  self.shapado_version_id = ShapadoVersion.where(:token => 'free').first.id
end
```

to

```
def set_shapado_version
  self.shapado_version_id = ShapadoVersion.where(:token => 'free').first.try(:id)
end
```

Here is the related merge request: https://gitorious.org/shapado/shapado/merge_requests/18

Answer (score 1):

```
def set_shapado_version
  self.shapado_version_id = ShapadoVersion.where(:token => 'free').first.id
end
```

are you sure there's a ShapadoVersion where token = 'free'?  I think Rails is complaining with this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your post. It's not an app that I've coded. I'm not sure what the code does. I've tried this fix: http://shapado.com/questions/rake-bootstrap-error-called-id-for-nil and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Using this post: http://shapado.com/questions/rake-bootstrap-error-called-id-for-nil
I managed to get it past the **rake bootstrap** by doing the following:

Changed the line 13 in shapado.yml to **true**

```
is_shapadocom: true
```

Added the following to config/payments.yml

```
secret: vtUQeOtUnYr7PGCLQ96Ul4zqpDUO4sOE
```

Added the following code hack. The original line is commented. Probably not the best approach.

```
def self.reload!
  #return unless AppConfig.is_shapadocom
  unless AppConfig.is_shapadocom
    ShapadoVersion.new(token: "free", price: 0).save!
    return
  end
  .
  .
  .
```

If anyone know Shapado please lookup my profile and contact me. I am interested in sharing experiences, especially on pushing to Heroku. It looks like a good app, but I can't find much in the way of documentation.