# Shapado: deploy on heroku failed with system package missing error

Tags: heroku, shapado

I have successfully ran the shapado rails application on my local system(am using ubuntu). But While running the bundle install, it fails with following error

> configure: error: Neither uuid/uuid.h nor uuid.h found - required for
>   brass, chert and flint (you may need to install the uuid-dev,
>   libuuid-devel or e2fsprogs-devel package)

Then I installed the packages by using

> sudo apt-get install uuid-dev
>   sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev

While running the rake task

> rake bootstrap RAILS_ENV=development

Got some nil error and fixed the same by applying below patch

> [Called id for nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107509/called-id-for-nil)

After this, I can able to run the application on my local successfully.

When I tried to deploy on Heroku it fails with

> configure: error: Neither uuid/uuid.h nor uuid.h found - required for brass, chert and flint (you may need to install the uuid-dev, libuuid-devel or e2fsprogs-devel package)

it tries to install the gem 'xapian-ruby', '1.2.7.1' and fails due to unavailable of packages.

Is any one facing the same issue. Suggest me to sort this out.

Comment: Why are you trying to use libqt on heroku? it is a GUI library, right?

Answer (score 0):

Deploying shapado to heroku would require you to make a custom buildpack that has the binary dependencies that shapado needs built in. Instructions on how to do that can be found here https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/11/13/hacking-buildpacks. It is possible though.