# Xapian-ruby on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am relatively new to deployment on heroku but after trying out an open source ruby on rails project, I figured out how to install the gems (and dependencies of gems) locally, but heroku gives me a hard time. There are two or three gems in question, for which i had to do the following locally:

## **

**sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev** # for nokogiri gem 
**sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev libqt4-core libqt4-gui** # for capybara gem
**sudo apt-get install uuid-dev** # required for xapian-ruby gem
**sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev** # required for xapian-ruby gem if qt not installed earlier
=======**

However, as I guessed heroku isnt smart enough to detect and install these gem dependencies. I looked up and spent some time on things like vulcan and heroku run bash but I dont get it conceptually? I also suspect that installing stuff through bash wont work after dyno restarts. And there is not enough documentation on vulcan to make matters worse. I tried all the steps but its simply too confusing.

What is the best approach for installing the gem environment(the libraries stated above). Any help is really appreciated!!!

Thanks,
H

Comment: Did you ever get any resolution to this? Did the answer below help?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Rails 3.2, you should be managing your gems using Bundler. Heroku is capable of installing directly from your Gemfile, so long as you're conforming to their [best practices](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler).

The libraries you cited will very likely already be available to your deployment on Heroku. All you need to worry about is bundling the correct gems – Heroku will do the rest.

**UPDATE**:

In order to get these dependencies installed, you'll need to do what Heroku terms *hacking a buildpack*. Assuming you're on the Cedar stack, you can follow Heroku's own documentation for hacking buildpacks [here](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/11/13/hacking-buildpacks).

Comment: thanks but unfortunately these libraries are not available on heroku as i get error while building native extensions.. So far I suspect gems are correctly bundled on heroku. Its just a question of the dependencies. A very similar problem  is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965302/shapado-deploy-on-heroku-failed-with-system-package-missing-error

Comment: ;I get configure: error: Neither uuid/uuid.h nor uuid.h found - required for brass, chert and flint (you may need to install the uuid-dev, libuuid-devel or e2fsprogs-devel package)

Comment: I tried doing it using vulcan but it isnt as straightforward as it looks. Anyways I will try it again,just to reiterate what i understand: 1. I get the source code of all these packages locally and build them using vulcan. 2. Create a build server using vulcan and deploy all the build from #1 to that build server. 3. Configure my app to use the created build server and I am done. Am I missing something here or is it what you suggest?

Comment: I would recommend bypassing any suggestion or step that you don't see in the Heroku docs. I followed those instructions and didn't have any issues myself.